# initialize list of different objects in inherited class

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, dictionary

I have a base class as follows

```cs
    protected BaseClasse()
    {
        this.myDic= new Dictionary<string, List<somethingThatWillChange>>();
    }

    protected Dictionary<string, List<somethingThatWillChange>> myDic{ get; set; }
```

However, this class will have two classes that will inherit from it. One of the inherited classes will need `new Dictionary<string, List<Type1>>()` and the other will need `new Dictionary<string, List<Type2>>()`.

Type1 and Type2 are classes and Type1 has 7 fields (name,age,time,job,car,salary,title) and Type2 has 3 fields (name,age,time).

So in the base class, I want to initialize or declare my dictionaries as `new Dictionary<string, List<somethingGeneric>>()`

and then in the two inherited classes, I want to initialize or convert this to the appropriate `List<type1>` and `List<type2>`

- I do NOT want to declare multiple dictionaries.
- I do NOT want to do inheritance on my Type1 and Type2 classes

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
public BaseClass<T>
{
    protected BaseClasse()
    {
        this.myDic= new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
    }

    protected Dictionary<string, List<T>> myDic{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
public BaseClass<T> {
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        this.myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
    }

    protected Dictionary<string, List<T>> myDic { get; set; }
}

public Type1Class : BaseClass<Type1> {
}

public Type2Class : BaseClass<Type2> {
}
```